# Analytic semigroup

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

Let $A$ be  the infinitesimal generator of analytic semigroup  $S(t)$ on a Hilbert space such that:
$$\|S(t)\|\le \frac{M}{t^{\gamma}}$$
what we get fot 
$$\|AS(t)\|\le ??$$

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Is there any other information on the resolvent of $A$? For example, does $0$ belong to $\rho(A)$?

Comment: yeah sure $0\in \rho(A)$, and the $\gamma$ is negative..

Comment: If $\gamma<0$, then $\frac{M}{t^\gamma}\to0$ as $t\to0$, so $S(t)\to0$ in the norm topology. This is clearly not the case.